# I'm getting a syntax error operand of '*' must be a pointer but has type "char"

Tags: c, char, syntax-error

I'm getting this error and I don't know why

```
void mem_move(void* dest, void* src, unsigned size)
{
    char* d = dest, * s = src;
    char buff[100];
    char* b = buff;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        *b[i] = *s[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        *d[i] = *b[i];
}


void main()
{
    char buffer[] = "one two three  ";
    mem_move(buffer + 3, buffer, 10);
    char buffer2[] = "one two three  ";
    mem_move(buffer2, buffer2 + 3, 10);
}
```

I should mention that I'm on visual studio community edition 2022

Comment: It's from `*b[i] = *s[i];` which should be `b[i] = s[i];`

Comment: `b[i]` and `d[i]` have a type of `char`.

Answer (score 1):

In these statements

```
*b[i] = *s[i];

*d[i] = *b[i];
```

you are dereferencing the pointers two times using the subscript operator `[]` and the dereference operator `*`.

Write

```
b[i] = s[i];
```

and

```
d[i] = b[i];
```

Pay attention to that according to the C standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```